# Python: How to store large numbers in a Pandas dataframe as int64 or float64?

Tags: python, pandas, casting, integer

Similar to this question, [Storing big numbers over 9000 digits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036751/storing-big-numbers-over-9-000-digits-in-python), I'm interested in storing large digits in a Pandas data frame where the `dtype` is `int64` or `float64` but not object. I have tried but I keep getting this error when I either initialize the dataframe or when I cast to `int64` or `float64`: `OverflowError: int too large to convert to float`.

Here is some sample code that raises an error:

```
data = [[4041067959774462618542251414053149763363284932506803841495981726909361589243016772093539952215008166854586458807896667612935940650616044271694578570770218354465319095565165551049760172710391683826002499005236096882016133967285292291606248423125012884140175919816849209382612886503119619750800600507246127268611380063066868139796774976684606993289391743637218529185641004454047725507720821393787669169611972814982330545723200072965546061194948505665350431588541107227045045135059495789131566496560507159916524037246652355679704655191235607257759392890459293292994869676442294348205840960197717998950931099935125824565443461965027936602550759188464075684122645652374411071687652948467619565381434911645676757024253483187841007912001722045733971195432548620690744725086837979031567344095323422174671522835282126126173748501439121944882602887928671532521816234961981946544118773557395130950306137831226533275921950157923776845085190156444450216692581322726107832236483226314003339464513548213142271415371910246088829012370639200542888385733241823213915919885883384151357374501359157931301139416090907994970949429195483607826525457136853740508614341446335314912887887891647364907817033609726890368372485038664354107037004105702300397408085198993506316238517085901918870189631204393632008524269869979074462426748217010716364884706958521730228474069227641283826703864839419845872269299777537, 10], [2, 15], [3, 14]]

  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['code1', 'code2'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
...
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

It's clear you can cast the array to np.array but note that this forces the `dtype` to be object and not an `int64` or `float64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data in array format by using `numpy.asarray()` method.
below is solution code for this question,

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

data = [[4041067959774462618542251414053149763363284932506803841495981726909361589243016772093539952215008166854586458807896667612935940650616044271694578570770218354465319095565165551049760172710391683826002499005236096882016133967285292291606248423125012884140175919816849209382612886503119619750800600507246127268611380063066868139796774976684606993289391743637218529185641004454047725507720821393787669169611972814982330545723200072965546061194948505665350431588541107227045045135059495789131566496560507159916524037246652355679704655191235607257759392890459293292994869676442294348205840960197717998950931099935125824565443461965027936602550759188464075684122645652374411071687652948467619565381434911645676757024253483187841007912001722045733971195432548620690744725086837979031567344095323422174671522835282126126173748501439121944882602887928671532521816234961981946544118773557395130950306137831226533275921950157923776845085190156444450216692581322726107832236483226314003339464513548213142271415371910246088829012370639200542888385733241823213915919885883384151357374501359157931301139416090907994970949429195483607826525457136853740508614341446335314912887887891647364907817033609726890368372485038664354107037004105702300397408085198993506316238517085901918870189631204393632008524269869979074462426748217010716364884706958521730228474069227641283826703864839419845872269299777537, 10], [2, 15], [3, 14]]

data_array = np.asarray(data) 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data_array, 
    columns=['code1', 'code2']
    )

print(df['code1'][0])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I want the `dtypes` of these items to be `int64` or `float64` and not object. When I print dtypes, it's still an object.

Comment: Hi @TeodoricoLevoff as far as I can see, there's limitation in terms of size of `np.float64` on your data. for example, your large data has exponent of 1381 whereas `np.float64` has maximum exponent of 308. try
```np.finfo(np.float64).max``` .

we can use np.float128, but in pandas that large number is considered as `inf` and hence the issue.